# How to Assign / Relate String to 2D Int Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

beginner to c++ , i have two arrays. 1 is String, the other is 2D array (int). How do I assign the artists to the scores??

```
int Artistlist()
{
    const int A1_SIZE = 5, A2_ROWSIZE =5, A2_COLSIZE =10;

    string Artist[A1_SIZE]={ "Degas", "Holbien", "Monet", "Matisse", "Valesquez" };

    int Scores[A2_ROWSIZE][A2_COLSIZE] =
    {
        {5,5,6,8,4,6,8,8,8,10},
        {8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8},
        {10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10},
        {5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {5,6,8,10,4,0,0,0,0,0}
    };
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "assign the artists to the scores." What are the scores of? Ten paintings apiece for each artist? Add some detail to what you're looking for. Frame the problem you're trying to solve.  What output would you want to see if things are working?

Comment: John,. for instance first row in Scores is to be assigned to Degas. etc. there are 5 artists and 5 rows (if so) of scores.. Output should be a display of all artists and their scores and artist who scored highest and artist who scored second

Comment: It looks like, then, you've already assigned them (kind of), because you know what scores go with what artist: `Artist[yourArtist]` has scores `Scores[yourArtist][0]` through `Scores[yourArtist][9]` (with `yourArtist` being between 0 and 4).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a std::map and a std::vector.

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> map;

std::vector<int> DegasScores;
DegasScores.push_back(5);
DegasScores.push_back(5);
DegasScores.push_back(6);
DegasScores.push_back(8);
DegasScores.push_back(4);
DegasScores.push_back(6);
DegasScores.push_back(8);
DegasScores.push_back(8);
DegasScores.push_back(10);

map["Degas"] = DegasScores;
```

Answer (score 0):

dude if the arrays are ordered correctly i think you should use

```
Artist[artistnum]
Scores[artistnum][0]
.
.
.
Scores[artistnum][9]
```

as John said.

Comment: so something like 
Artist[0]=Scores[1][1];

Comment: i mean the Artist[0]'s points are stored in Scores[0][0] to Scores[0][9] because its ordered!

Comment: thanks shervin,,.. what would be easiet way to find average for each artist?

Comment: sorry for the delay. and the best way is to do this:

Comment: `int ave;for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)ave+=Scores[artistnum][i];ave/=10;`